# Can awscli be used in AWS Codebuild buildspec running on a custom image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codebuild, buildspec

If a Codebuild project runs on a custom image that has awscli preinstalled, but not configured for that AWS account, would it be still possible to run `aws *` in that project's buildspec without updating its AWS credentials there first?

In other words, are these credentials made available by Codebuild (e.g. via providing this information in automatically picked up environment variables) , or if I am using a custom image, it is up to me to take care of that explicitly, and `aws *` is only expected to work in buildspec out of the box without additional efforts on Codebuild managed images?

(I mean configuration/credentials for the account and role the Codebuild project in question operates in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach an IAM service role with your AWS Codebuild project, you don't need to configure AWS cli. IAM service role is part of environment configuration and this role will be assumed whenever you try to access resources in AWS. This goes same for your custom image for AWS Codebuild as well.

Comment: Thank you! Out of interest, which mechanism is used for that, i.e. how is that information passed to awscli in the image? It doesn't seem to be files in ~/.aws or environment variables...

Comment: You’re welcome! That's an interesting question and I did not know about the mechanism behind it. So, upon looking into the docs, I found out that AWS CLI uses the source profile's credentials to call AWS STS and request temporary credentials for the specified role. The user in the source profile must have permission to call sts:assume-role for the role in the specified profile. The role must have a trust relationship that allows the user in the source profile to use the role. The process of retrieving and then using temporary credentials for a role is often referred to as assuming the role.

Comment: Thank you again, this is very interesting, but I was trying to understand what medium is used to pass those temporary credentials to the awscli on the image. When it starts, is has to read these credentials (arranged by Codebuild via STS, as you explained) from a few standard sources, e.g. env vars or files in home folder, if the previous attempt fails etc. - which method is employed if you happen to know? I couldn't find it in the docs yet...